# Post Request Powershell

Tags: powershell, post

I would like to use an post request with powershell. But I am getting an error that the website doesn't work properly without javascript enabled.

Has anybody ideas, how to fix this problem? the software developer suggested using chrome. but i would have to map the call via powershell.

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

$body = @{
 "client"="cbd3a32fafb096"
 "request-type"="authentication"
 "username"="usrname"
 
} | ConvertTo-Json

$header = @{
 "Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  "User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Mobile Safari/537.36"

} 

$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://myurl"  -Body $body -Headers $header
$Result
```

Comment: Using a web driver like selenium or instantiating internet explorer (whilst it is still available and supported I might add...) could be an option. Also if the action can be performed in a browser I would suggest inspecting the request in chrome under the network tab and right clicking on the request and "Copy" -> "Copy as PowerShell" (I suggest modifying the request pasted by adding `-SessionVariable` and using `-WebSession` in any sub sequent requests.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Are ther any other possibilities to run a post request with a script in background? thanks in advance!

Comment: You could potentially use `Invoke-WebRequest -method post -Uri "http://myurl" -Body $body -Headers $header` instead of `Invoke-restmethod` and look at the response of `$Result.ParsedHtml`.